# jQuery Nested sets and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, nested-sets

I'm searching for some ready-made solution for working with nested sets with PHP and jQuery.

I know about nested sets and I know how to work with PHP and jQuery but I want to save my time  using ready-made solution.

What is the best solution?

Comment: How nested sets (and the way data stored in database) are related to client-side?

Comment: *ready-made solution* for what exactly?

Comment: I want to use ajax for changing tree or for adding new elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question doesn't make much sense, and its scope is too broad. Please explain what you have tried, or post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution to handle nested sets (or any other data structure) would be **json_encode/json_decode**

Send data from PHP to JavaScript:

```
$data = new PHPComplexData();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Receive data in client side:

```
$.get('data.php', function(data){
    var jsData = eval('('+data+')');
    //You have a JavaScript object
});
```

Send data from JavaScript to PHP

```
var jsData = new JSComplexData();
$.post('data.php', {data:$.toJSON(jsData)});
```

Receive data in server side

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

you need [jquery-json plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to use **$.toJSON** function

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but if I'm reading you right, you're looking for some kind of jQuery treeview control?

Maybe something like this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm

or this: http://be.twixt.us/jquery/treeViewCollapsed.php

or [any number of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tree+menu)....?